# Find if url refers to existing object

Tags: java, url

i have a lot of URL to show it on client. But i have to choose urls that to existing objects (in my situation - images). Do somebody know how can i get if  my url refer to image that was not deleted from storage?

Comment: Response code might be helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like

```
URL url = new URL("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
int statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();//OK if returned value is 200
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try to open a stream:

```
public static boolean exists(URL url) throws IOException {
    try {
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        return inputStream != null;
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
        return false;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(exists(new URL("https://www.google.de/images/srpr/logo11w.png")));
    System.out.println(exists(new URL("https://www.google.de/images/srpr/foo.png")));
}
```